# Spring data mongoDB push operation with multiple fields are not working

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, aggregation

I have a set of data objects in MongoDB as-

```
[
    { "status" : "passed", "version" : "124" , "value" : 6 },
    { "status" : "passed", "version" : "123" , "value" : 10 },
    { "status" : "failed", "version" : "123" , "value" : 16 }
]
```

and i want to get it in a format like -

```
[
    { 
    version: 124,
    "series" :[ 
        { 
            "name" : "passed", 
            "value" : 6 
        }
      ]
    },
    {
    version: 123,
    "series" : [
         { 
             "name" : "passed", 
             "value" : 10 
         },
         { 
             "name" : "failed", 
             "value" : 16 
         }
      ]
    }
]
```

how should i write the query?
I wrote query like

I have written a query like:

```
Aggregation.group("version").push(new BasicDBObject("name","$status").append("value", "$value")).as("series");
```

using the aggregate query above, I'm getting like:

```
[
    { 
    version: 124,
    "series" :[ 
        { 
          "name" : null, 
          "value" : 6 
        }
      ]
    },
    {
    version: 123,
    "series" : [
         { 
           "name" : null, 
           "value" : 10
         },
         { 
           "name" : null, 
           "value" : 16 
         }
      ]
    }
]
```

It seems that the value of the status is not taken in the object. How can I resolve this?

Comment: I am doing the same and it worked well for me. What is the version of Spring-data-mongodb used by you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Query is like:

```
db.results.aggregate([{
     {
       "$group": {
             "_id": {
                  "status": "$status",
                  "version": "$version",
              },
             "count": {
                  "$sum": 1
              }
            }
        }, {
            $group: {
                _id: "$_id.version",
                "series": {
                    $push: {
                        "status": "$_id.status",
                        "value": "$count"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]);
```

So I have to add the aggregation query as:

```
Aggregation.group("version").push(new BasicDBObject("_id", "$_id.status").append("value", "$value")).as("series");
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried with mongo aggregation. Try in the shell.
I am not familiarised with spring.

```
db.getCollection('Test1').aggregate([
{
$group:{
    _id:"$version",
    version:{$first:"$version"},
    series:{
        $push:{
            name:"$status",
            value:"$value"
            }
        }
    }
},
{$project:{_id:0}}
])
```

Comment: Thanks for your reponse, but I need spring boot mongoDB query.